# how to manually construct a tuple in Apache Pig on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a text file and each line is a string, I want to construct one tuple from all the strings in the text file. Wondering how to implement in Pig?

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lin Ma : If the objective is to have each line as a field in Tuple then, we can make use of the below snippet.

**Input :**

```
line1 data ....
line2 data ....
line3 data ....
lineN data .....
```

**Pig Script :**

```
text_data = LOAD 'text_data.txt'  USING  PigStorage('\n') AS (line_data:chararray);
text_data_gpr_all = GROUP text_data ALL;
required_data = FOREACH text_data_gpr_all GENERATE BagToTuple(text_data.line_data) ;
DUMP required_data;
```

**Output :**

```
((line1 data ....,line2 data ....,line3 data ....,lineN data .....))
```

**Ref :** http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToTuple.html

Comment: thanks for the details and tried your code, it seems there is an additional ()? do you know why?

Comment: What I need is (line1 data ....,line2 data ....,line3 data ....,lineN data .....), which is one brackets.

Comment: @LinMa : We are seeing the result of DUMP. DUMP command will always display the data in a tuple. Existing data is tuple and DUMP will display the tuple data in tuple and hence we are seeing two parenthesis. If you are seeing the result in a file using STORE command then you will be seeing a single parenthesis for tuple  Ref : http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#pl_dump